# Ubuntu Vertical Sync on OpenGL in c++

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, tearing, vertical-sync

i've tearing problem in my OpenGL application on Ubuntu, how can i resolve it? (my notebook has an integrated Intel video card)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Forgot to ask, have you enabled double buffering in your OpenGL code? It will help if you are experiencing flicker.

If you are using GLUT, you can enable double buffering by using `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | whatever other flags you are using e.g. GLUT_DEPTH);` for initializing the display mode.
and instead of `glFlush()` you should call `glutSwapBuffers()` to display the rendered frame.

Try changing the vsync settings using the `driconf` tool, it is available in Ubuntu's repositories, run `apt-get install driconf` to install it.

There is a setting called "Synchronization with vertical refresh (swap intervals)" which has four levels: Never, default off, default on, always

See also: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/11/advanced-opengl-3d-rendering-configurator-for-ubuntu/

Comment: The double buffers mode is already in use, and the "Synchronization with vertical refresh (swap intervals)" parameter is already in always :(